# Elastic Search Must vs Should vs ExcludeFilters

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

Can someone elaborate on these three filters in elastic search namely must, should, excludeFilters.
Are these parts of bool queries which come under compound category of queries in elastic search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`must` is the same as logical AND operator and `should` is the same as logical OR operator

These clauses are used to combine multiple conditions (using [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)) when you are creating your DSL query

All these queries are included inside the bool query. For example

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {},
      "should": {},
      "filter": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1:**

should (contribute to relevancy score) this means that when you use a should clause, then the search results are returned based on a number of factors like doc count, length of the field, frequency, total term frequency etc.

Whereas in the case of `filter` (doesn't contribute to relevancy score), this means that it just gives an answer of yes/no i.e whether a document matches or not. (It does not consider other factors as `must` and `should` clause considers)

Comment: Does Filter only works with must clause i.e. the query (clause) which is being searched should be present in the documents. Lets say you got movies searched by titles from a movie elastic dataset, so the use case of filter can be to after getting the matched results you wan to only show those movies which have a rating of 3 or more. Is the understanding correct ?

Comment: {
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "should": [{
          "match": {
              "make": "Birdman"
          }
      }, {
          "match": {
              "make": "Avengers"
          }
      }],
      "filter" : {
          "term": {
              "rating": "5"
           }
       }
    }
  }
}

Comment: @Aditya filter clause acts like a `must` clause only. The only difference is that with the `filter` clause the score of the query is ignored, and with `must` clause, the score of the query is there. And it is not necessary to have a must clause along with the filter clasue

Comment: @Aditya yes, after getting the matched results if you want to only show those movies which have a rating of 3 or more only, then you can use filter clause

Comment: Is there any other use case of filters apart from this which is used commonly.

Comment: should (contribute to relevancy score) & exclude (doesn't contribute to relevancy score). This is also common phrase. can you elaborate on the relevancy score part.

Comment: @Aditya please go through the updated part of the answer, to get more understanding of `should` and `filter` clause

Comment: Thanks @ESCoder for quick response 

Comment: @Aditya please go through the answer, and let me know if now your issue is resolved

Comment: ,yes this resolves the issue. One Point, do you have some idea of spring data elastic search. Is there a way to create your own index and document via apis in that, because for searching purpose we can directly make the use elastic search repository and write the methods exposed to get the result

Comment: @Aditya yes, I have some idea but I am not an expert in that. But it would be better if you can ask a separate question regarding this, as there are other forks in the community that are experts in *spring data elastic search*. And please don't forget to upvote and accept the above answer as well ;-)